# sh404sef problem

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Im using Joomfish with two different languages. I have translated all the categorys and etc with joomfish. Everything works fine in site, but url-s are also in main language ( won´t be translated).

Do I have to translate them in sh404sef also? 
or somebody can tell me what might be the problem?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the settings in sh404sef - you can view settings by component:

```
Components -> sh404SEF -> Configuration Tab -> sh404sef configuration -> By Component tab
```

That will give you access to the ability to change things depending upon language files and stuff.

Not sure if that helps - but it's where I would start.  Also the dev's are very active on their forums and are a great help in situations like this.  I can't remember how nicely Joomfish & sh404SEF play together.